# Please helpQString remove function to remove const string

Tags: qt, visual-c++, qt4

I want to remove blank space from a const string, but when i used remove function its showing error that const string cant modify.

```
const QString abc = "hello world";
QString def       = " ";
QString mk = abc .remove(def);  // Here error saying const cant change
```

Please Help

Comment: You can't. You have to create a non-const copy. Or make the string non-const in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify a const String. QString::remove returns a reference to abc, so remove works on abc, mk is not a copy but abc again!! Look for functions which are const functions if you want to operate on a const object.

EDIT:

```
const QString abc = "hello world";
QString ijk = abc;
QString def       = " ";
QString mk = ijk .remove(def);  // Here error saying const cant change
```

Comment: Can you please help how can i do this. QTassistant also saying same but dont know how to make it working.

Comment: But here  we are using tem variablr ijk. Is it possible to do with out using ijk variable.

Comment: No - unless you start with QString abc instead of const QString. Everything else is dirty (e.g. const casting the address of abc to a non-const pointer and modifying the const object via the non-const pointer)

Answer (score 0):

The same operation without additional variable:

```
const QString abc = "hello world";
QString def = " ";
QString mk = abc;
mk.remove(def);
```